# Pickup at Frankfurt Airport at Terminal 1 during construction work

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, event-based-effects, fra

The arrival level of the Terminal 1 at Frankfurt Airport is not accessible by car due to [construction work](http://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/frankfurt_airport/en/parking/altered-traffic-routing-t1.html). The airport administration recommends use of car parks P1 to P5 instead. To me, this proposal seems quite impractical:

- These car parks are much further away than the car lane on the arrivals level. I would not want to walk that far with kids and heaps of luggage if it is not absolutely necessary.
- Meeting the pickup person in the car parks would be quite difficult since they are huge. There do not seem to be any designated meeting points, at least the airport administration does not mention any.

I suspect that the administration has recommended a solution which is easy for them but not necessarily comfortable for travellers. The obvious alternative is to pickup on the departure level, which is still accessible.

Would this be possible?

Or can you think of any other more practical alternative?

Comment: How did you get on?

Answer (score 2):

> These car parks are much further away than the car lane on the arrivals level. 
>   I would not want to walk that far with kids and heaps of luggage if it is not
>   absolutely necessary.

It's not that far. Even if you are unfamiliar with the place, it won't take more than 10 minutes to find your way to the parking deck after you cleared customs. They even have luggage trolleys and elevators everywhere on the airport.

> Meeting the pickup person in the car parks would be quite difficult since they
>   are huge. There do not seem to be any designated meeting points, at least the
>   airport administration does not mention any.

There is a [designated meeting point](http://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/frankfurt_airport/en/misc/container/Uebersichtsplan-T1-und-T2-Sep-2014/jcr:content.file/t1t2_0914.pdf) on the inside of the arrival terminal, close to the taxi stand on the outside and an information booth on the inside. Or just tell your friends to meet in front of one of the car rental companies. Very easy to find and usually not too crowded, so it's easy to find each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have your passengers walk the skyway over to the hotel, and pick them up in front of the hotel.